# SSRS: Parse results from a SQL Server query that has an XML Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am looking at the following query:

```
SELECT  txt.ID, txt.Rev, txt.Words,
        flds.ReferenceName
FROM    Fields flds (NOLOCK) 
        JOIN WorkItemLongTexts txt (NOLOCK) 
            ON flds.FldID = txt.FldID
WHERE   flds.ReferenceName = 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps'
```

The third column (txt.Words) returns this value:

```
<steps id="0" last="3">
  <step id="1" type="ValidateStep">
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Step 1</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Result 1</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <description />
  </step>
  <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Step 2</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Result 2</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <description />
  </step>      
</steps>
```

Clearly I can easily parse this out with a .net client side application.  However, I would like to take this query directly into a SSRS report.

Is there a way to get the data from this column into a SSRS consumable dataset like this:
1 | ValidateStep | Step 1 | Result 1
2 | ValidateStep | Step 2 | Result 2

(or anything similar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TSQL's OpenXM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx)L functionality to get a rowset from your xml data, however you want a combination of elements and attributes so it will be a little work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `ssrs` but here is how I would do it in a regular query. Perhaps it is something you can use.
I have simplified your sample and uses a table variable instead. I assume that the XMLColumn has datatype `xml`.

```
-- Sample table
declare @T table (ID int, XMLColumn xml)

-- Insert sample data
insert into @T values
(1,'
<steps id="0" last="3">
  <step id="1" type="ValidateStep">
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Step 1</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Result 1</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <description />
  </step>
  <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Step 2</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <parameterizedString>
      <text>Result 2</text>
    </parameterizedString>
    <description />
  </step>      
</steps>')

-- Duplcate first row
insert into @T 
select 2, XMLColumn
from @T


-- The query
select
  ID as RowID,
  s.value('@id', 'int') as ID, 
  s.value('@type', 'varchar(15)') as [Type],
  s.value('parameterizedString[1]/text[1]', 'varchar(15)') as Step, 
  s.value('parameterizedString[2]/text[1]', 'varchar(15)') as Result 
from @T
```

Result

```
RowID       ID          Type            Step            Result
----------- ----------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
1           1           ValidateStep    Step 1          Result 1
1           2           ValidateStep    Step 2          Result 2
2           1           ValidateStep    Step 1          Result 1
2           2           ValidateStep    Step 2          Result 2
```